# Stock calculation during sales

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `StockCard` table with below schema:

```
create table StockCard(
    id int(9) zerofill primary key auto_increment,
    ref_page smallint(3) not null,
    ref_number int(9) not null,
    sur_key int unsigned null,
    description varchar(255),
    warehouse_product_id int(9) zerofill not null,
    sc_date datetime not null,
    qty int not null,
    price double(15,2) not null,
    reserved_qty int not null,
    left_qty int not null,
    status boolean not null, /* true = buy, false = sell*/
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (warehouse_product_id) REFERENCES Warehouse_Product(id),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (ref_page) REFERENCES Page(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

For now, when I want to sell a product I use `LIMIT` to know whether I got enough `left_qty`/stock for selling that product. Below is my query, which runs in a `for loop` as long as `avail_stock` still below `ordered_qty`:

```
SELECT SUM(StockCard.left_qty) AS avail_qty FROM StockCard 
LEFT JOIN Warehouse_Product ON Warehouse_Product.id = StockCard.warehouse_product_id
WHERE Warehouse_Product.product_id = {product_id}
AND StockCard.status = 1 AND left_qty > 0
ORDER BY sc_date ASC, id ASC
LIMIT {row_limit} 
//this row_limit will increase in every loop as long as the SUM smaller than the ordered qty
```

My question here, is it true that by using my approach above it will improve my query performance or should I just delete the `LIMIT`? Feel free to give other approach..

Here is the simplified version of my issue: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36ef5

Comment: When LEFT JOIN, put the right table conditions in the ON clause, otherwise the outer join behaves just like a regular inner join!

Comment: If anything, you should replace your `for` loop with a set-based operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `LIMIT`, it would be a lot of queries generated. See the fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e04e9/29), first you need to calculate the sum of previous (see `x2` or `minqty`) and sum of previous and current (see `x1` or `maxqty`) then use them to filter what you need.

```
SELECT x3.*
FROM
    ( SELECT sc1.*, IFNULL(SUM(sc2.left_qty),0) maxqty
    FROM StockCard sc1
      LEFT JOIN StockCard sc2 ON sc2.id <= sc1.id
    WHERE sc1.status = 1 AND sc2.status = 1 AND sc1.warehouse_product_id = 1 AND sc2.warehouse_product_id = 1
    GROUP BY sc1.id
    ORDER BY sc2.sc_date ASC, sc2.id ASC ) x1
  LEFT JOIN
    ( SELECT sc1.*, IFNULL(SUM(sc2.left_qty),0)+1 minqty
    FROM StockCard sc1
      LEFT JOIN StockCard sc2 ON sc2.id < sc1.id
    WHERE sc1.status = 1 AND sc2.status = 1 AND sc1.warehouse_product_id = 1 AND sc2.warehouse_product_id = 1
    GROUP BY sc1.id
    ORDER BY sc2.sc_date ASC, sc2.id ASC ) x2
  ON x1.id = x2.id
  LEFT JOIN StockCard x3 ON x3.id <= x1.id 
    AND x3.warehouse_product_id = sc1.warehouse_product_id
WHERE IFNULL(x2.minqty,0) <= 15 -- > change these
  AND x1.maxqty >= 15 --> change these
```

For example when the table contains: 15, 2 and 3, minqty and maxqty would be:

```
qty min max
15    1  15
 2   16  17
 3   18  21
```

Comment: After using your query, I think you need another clause in the nested query. The perfect one should be  `WHERE sc1.status = 1 AND sc2.status = 1 AND sc1.warehouse_product_id = 1 AND sc2.warehouse_product_id = 1`. With your query `sc2` will also sum `left_qty` that not satisfy `warehouse_product_id = 1`. Please change your answer if you agree with me, so I could give mark yours as accepted answer.

Comment: Also your  `LEFT JOIN StockCard x3 ON x3.id <= x1.id` needs to be `LEFT JOIN StockCard x3 ON x3.id <= x1.id AND x3.warehouse_product_id = sc1.warehouse_product_id`. And need to add `x3.status = 1` to the last `WHERE` clause.